# Remove macOS Dock icon with a command in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, dock, defaults

I'm trying to find the terminal command which can remove an icon from the dock, but I can't find the solution.

I tried the defaults read / defaults write command but it doesn't seem to have the delete function.

The plist is `com.apple.dock`.

It's curious because the graphical function do it well, and I searched in the console, I don't find what the graphical function call..
I need to do find it to create a removal script..

[image: defaults read com.apple.dock]

[image: Remove icon from dock with the graphic function]

If someone have a solution, it could be cool.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918547/how-to-remove-an-application-icon-from-dock-from-mac-osx-mavericks. You may have to add the removal twice as was their solution.

Answer (score 14):

I recommend using [dockutil](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil) for this. You can either download and install this [directly from github](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil/releases), or you can install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with the command

```
brew install dockutil
```

Once installed, you can use a command like this to remove an app from the dock

```
dockutil --remove 'Microsoft Excel'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove all icons, you can use this terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array
```

Comment: Followed by `killall Dock` to restart the now-empty Dock.

Comment: this will fix most situations, basically cleans out the plist file in your preferences, however, MDM/MacosX Server administration profiles sometimes can leave some kind of shadow dock icons with '?' that seem to be a mystery of how they can be removed - especially if the MDM is no longer an active profile.